# Checking if ID exists and also if another column is null and updating another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am about to implement an update statement on a table. I know it sounds really simple, but I'm not able to get through it logically.

**Scenario:**

There is a table I have with the below format, that gets data everyday through a process. The columns on the table are as follows:

PKID    |   RecordID     |      ThirdPartyID    |     Action    |   DATEADDED

PKID: The auto incremental Primary Key.
RecordID: Can have duplicates.
ThirdpartyID: Can be multiple values and also accepts NULLS.
Action: The column that needs to be updated
DateAdded: Contains the GETDATE() of when the record is imported into the table.

**Problem:**

There is a process that imports new records into this table everyday. When the records are inserted for a day, I need to check the following:

1. Check if the newly Inserted RecordIDs are already existing in the table.
2. If the RecordID entered today, is already there in the table (there can be multiple entries of the same RecordID in the old records),

   - Check if the ThirdPartyID is NULL in the old records for that RecordID.
   - If the ThirdPartyID exists in any of the old records for that RecordID, update the Action Column with 'Multiple Entries.'

     - Else do nothing.

Please let me know if I can provide any further clarification or details in this regard.

Comment: Easier way is to use a temp table for new records: 1. Load new records to a temp table. 2. compare the temp table to the main table where the RecordID exists in the main table. 3. If it exists in the main table then check whether the ThirdPartyID is NULL. 4. If it is not null then update Action column to "Multiple Entries", else do nothing.

Comment: I am not able to figure out the SQL for that. I tried using a ROW_NUMBER () over partition BY and assign ROW numbers to all the duplicate RecordIDs. But I am not able to move forward from there.

There can be multiple RecordID rows that have same value, If any of those rows has the ThirdPArtyID as NOT NULL, I can update the Action column.

Comment: I've attempted an answer to your issue. Not sure if I understand your problem fully though :)

Comment: Really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach the problem like this:

1. Load new data into a Temp table.
2. Inner Join the 2 tables on RecordID which will join only if the RecordID exists in both tables...
3. update the Action column to "Multiple Entries" if the ThirdPartyID field is also null.

Script should be something like this:

```
UPDATE Main
SET Action = 'Multiple Entries'
FROM Main INNER JOIN Temp ON Main.RecordID = Temp.RecordID
WHERE Main.ThirdPartyID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I  tried this out and currently testing it out. Will let you know the results.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a copy of the inserted data by OUTPUT-ing it to a table variable, then perform the update by joining to the original table. e.g:

```
DECLARE @inserted TABLE
(PKID           INT
,RecordID       INT
,ThirdPartyID   INT
,Action         VARCHAR(MAX)
,DateAdded      DATE);

INSERT TestTable1
(RecordID
,ThirdPartyID
,Action
,DateAdded)
    OUTPUT
     inserted.PKID
    ,inserted.RecordID
    ,inserted.ThirdPartyID
    ,inserted.Action
    ,inserted.DateAdded
    INTO @inserted
    (PKID
    ,RecordID
    ,ThirdPartyID
    ,Action
    ,DateAdded)
VALUES 
(1
,2
,NULL
,GETDATE());

UPDATE t
SET ThirdPartyID = 'Multiple Entries'
FROM @inserted i
JOIN TestTable1 t
ON i.RecordID = t.RecordID
WHERE t.ThirdPartyID IS NOT NULL;
```